# nginx reverse proxy point toward wrong app after app container reboot

Tags: nginx, docker-compose, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

a project use a nginx reverse proxy to checking on 80 and 443 to

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  nginx:
    container_name: "nginx"
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./nginx.Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - ./config:/config
      - ./default:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - /etc/letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt:ro
      - /tmp/acme_challenge:/tmp/acme_challenge
    #restart: always
    networks:
      - app-network

networks:
  app-network:
    external: true
    name: network-name
```

using a nginx.conf like that :

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name website-test.com;
location / {
        return 302 https://website-test.com/;
    }

}
 
server {

    listen 443 ssl;
  
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name website-test.com;

    #ssl_certificate 
    #ssl_certificate_key 


    location /ui/ {
        proxy_pass "http://front-app:80/";
    }
    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass "http://api-app:3000/";
}
```

and the applicaton docker compose :

```
version: "3.9"`your text`

services:
  front:
    hostname: front-app
    image: ghcr.io/app:front-app-latest
    depends_on:
      - api-app
    networks:
      - app-network

  api:
    hostname: api-app
    image: ghcr.io/app:api-app-latest
    depends_on:
      - bdd
    networks:
      - app-network
```

the nginx and the applications are on the same network, and both have their own container, the issue come from the moment I update the applications docker image, and then run a
docker compose down following by a docker compose up
after that the nginx redirection do not point anymore to the right application.

Does anyone kown how to solve this ?

thanks

Tried multiple change with hostname, container name, online research.